# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file but getting an expected token, `{` at position 0.

**SolaceConnetionParser.js**

```
class SolaceConnectionParser {
    constructor() { }

    //TODO: cannot parse json correctly
    parse(filepath) {
        const connectionArgs = [];
        console.log('File path: ' + filepath);
        const rawData = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8').toString;
        const contents = JSON.parse(rawData);
        return contents;
    }
}

module.exports = SolaceConnectionParser;

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const parser = new SolaceConnectionParser();
const filepath = path.join(__dirname + '../../../configs/test.json');
console.log(parser.parse(filepath));
```

**test.json**:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

**Expected:**
Rest of statements in code should output to console (i.e.: JSON contents).
**Actual:**

```
$ node SolaceConnectionParser.js
File path: C:\Users\u589329\Desktop\angular\dashboard_backend\dashboard_backend\src\configs\test.json
undefined:1
{
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at SolaceConnectionParser.parse (C:\Users\u589329\Desktop\angular\dashboard_backend\dashboard_backend\src\app\solace\SolaceConnectionParser.js:9:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\u589329\Desktop\angular\dashboard_backend\dashboard_backend\src\app\solace\SolaceConnectionParser.js:26:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the JSON is malformed and invalid.  Have you looked at the JSON?

Comment: hey yeah i added the `test.json` file. its properly constructed thats why im confused

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are represented as `String`s and `fs.readFileSync()` returns a `Buffer`.

Change

`const rawData = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8');`

to

`const rawData = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8').toString();`

and you should be good to go.

Comment: ah, tried that but got the following: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1`. also updated my code in the question to make it simpler.

Comment: any ideas? a little lost here

Answer (score 0):

after applying Rob Raisch's answer and also trimming the string, problem was solved.

`const rawData = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8').toString().trim();`